# Need to add $_POST['link'] to the file name for anything uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I'm having difficulty figure out how to append the value of $_POST['link'] to the prefix of files that are being uploaded to my upload.php script. I've tried a hand full of things and over two hours of googling. However,  I'm having trouble understanding what needs to be changed. I've been working on scripts for the project for ten days now and I'm starting to burn out. Anything advice you can provide would really help me out and will be greatly appreciated.

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "../../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is a Video- " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 400000000000000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "webm" && $imageFileType != "mpg" && $imageFileType != "mpeg" && $imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "m4p" && $imageFileType != "m4v" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "wmv" && $imageFileType != "mov" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only WEBM, MPG, MPEG, MP4, M4P, M4V, AVI, WMV, MOV files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

echo $_POST['link'];
?>
```

Comment: Simpler to just change this line `$target_file = $target_dir . $_POST['link'] . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo, or user-defined error at the first nested if condition: `else { $uploadOk = 1;}`, this will return true even if the flow is incorrect, first change to `else {$uploadOk = 0;}`

To add a prefix to the value of the uploaded file, just do this

```
$myprefix = "VID";
$client_filename = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];
$final_name = $myprefix . $client_filename;
$path = "path/to/folder/" .  $final_name;
```

Then when uploading, use the new name:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"], $path);
```